# RxJS: filtering an array of elements within an array

Tags: arrays, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Ok, I have tried numerous combinations and permutations of `flatMap`, `filter` and all sorts of RxJS operators, but I do not seem to be able to solve my problem.

I have an `ITag` interface in TypeScript, which contains a property `selectable`. I have an `Observable` of an array of these `ITags`, and I would like to produce another `Observable` of an array of `ITags` where this `selectable` property is true.

Here is some pseudocode which is the culmination of about three hours' of head-scratching:

```
protected getCategories(): Observable<ITag[]> {
  return this.getModule()
    .flatMap((module) => Observable.from(module.descendants))
    .filter((descendant) => descendant.selectable);
}
```

Here, `this.getModule()` returns an `Observable<ITag>`, and `module.descendants` is an `Array<ITag>`. The compiler current complains:

> Type 'Observable< ITag>' is not assignable to type 'Observable< ITag[] >'.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you want to transform Observable<ITag> to Observable<ITag[]> you first need to decide when will an array be emitted. Should it be emitted only once when the getModule observable is completed? Or maybe for every source item?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the signature of the method what you want is probably more along the lines of this.

```js
protected getCategories(): Observable<ITag[]> {
  return this.getModule()
    .reduce((acc, descendant) => { acc.push(descendant); return acc; }, [])
    .map((descendants) => descendants.filter(d => d.selectable));
}
```

This way you get one event which contains a list of ITags as the value. You can read more about the reduce operator [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/reduce.html).

Your code is fine it's just that it produces and Observable of ITag, not an array of ITag. So you'll get an event for each ITag individually.

If that's what you want you just need to **change the return type** of the method so it fits. You get that error because you are returning **Observable< ITag >** when the function definition says it should be **Observable< ITag[] >**.

```js
protected getCategories(): Observable<ITag> {
  return this.getModule()
    .flatMap((module) => Observable.from(module.descendants))
    .filter((descendant) => descendant.selectable);
}
```

Comment: I'm not at work so I can't test this, but I don't think it's going to work. For one thing, `this.getModule()` returns an `Observable<ITag>`, not an `ITag`, thus `this.getModule().descendants` isn't going to work is it? Also, the return type really needs to be an `Observable<ITag[]>`, since there will be more than one tag that satisfies the filter.

Comment: ok, I think that might change the solution a bit.. especially the fact that this.getModule returns an observable.

Comment: are you sure there's no way for the module to observable to emit Observable< ITag[]> ? or that you can't just collect the tags into an array when you use them. The thing is transforming Observable<ITag> into Observable<ITag[]> might not be as easy as it seems. More info on how you plan to use the tags or how the tags are generated in the first place might help find a better solution. :)

Comment: I changed the solution to use the reduce operator to transform the Observable< ITag> into an Observable< ITag[]>. It's not tested though, hopefully the types match up, let me know. :)